# Keyboard get disabled on Android Studio on Mac

Tags: android-studio

While coding sometimes I have to press the undo keyboard shortcut longer than usual. Command+Z

If I press them too long the keyboard get disabled and I have to restart Android Studio

I press them too long to repeat many edits to a file. Then my keyboard is disabled.

I do not know why and I do not know how to enable it back.

I do not want to restart my IDE many times.

Anyone know how to prevent keyboard from being disabled on Android Studio?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I dealt with the same problem.

'hold down key' (long press) in Mac trigger a special character.
looks like that Android Studio doesn't support special characters.

to disable this function in Mac open the Terminal and enter the following command:

```
defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
```

to enable this function - just replace the command to true:

```
defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool true
```

after you enter the disable command - closing Android Studio and starting over will resolve that problem for good.

source:
http://osxdaily.com/2011/08/04/enable-key-repeat-mac-os-x-lion

Comment: Sadly, after trying the suggestion above it didn't resolve the issue for me.
Worth mentioning - this is Mojave with latest Android Studio and I have 2 keyboard layouts.

Comment: You may also need to log out and log back in for this to take effect (Mojave)

Answer (score 9):

Press the key 'x' and hold it for 5 seconds. The keyboard will be back to normal again.

Comment: easter egg it is!